# What will replace the question mark?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Please find out what word should replace the question mark.

```
      apple      |   garlic    |     amla
----------------------------------------------
  pointed gourd  |      ?      |    radish
----------------------------------------------
      guava      |  pineapple  |  watermelon
```

And explain the logic.

Comment: Is the word should be from the other given names or totally different word?

Comment: [Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BjvC.png)

Answer (score 1):

The '?' should be replaced by the word

> FREE.

This is because

> The middle square is always FREE.
>  
>  [image: Bingo]

Comment: Questions tagged as "Lateral Thinking" are the best.  Complete license to be silly.  :)

Comment: I really like this one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is my logic.

> Replacing the $?$ mark with pineapple gives us-- guava $?$ watermelon, which asks us for an option between two very similar things. So pineapple is the likely word.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> Pineapple.

Explanation:

> If I replace it with pineapple, then all the fruits will come in line (diagonals) and the veggies are distinguished. Then corners are taken by fruits and sides by vegetables except for pineapple, which is the center point that joins all fruits. (Considering [amla as a fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllanthus_emblica))

Visualization:

> [image]

Comment: Whats *lateral thinking* here?

Comment: Well, the questions seem like `?` will be replaced by some other thing, but it may be supposed to make a pattern by moving some other thing in place if `?` which is not so straight.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

> pen.

because

> pen pineapple apple pen form loop . other items are kept to just distract . https://youtu.be/Ct6BUPvE2sM - link to song.

image

> [image]

Comment: Seriously???????